# using qr code to open an internal page in ionic 2

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic2, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I'm new in ionic 2 and cordova development and I'm testing the cordova plugin "barcode scanner" to see what I can do with it.
I wanna use the plugin to read a QR code that contains the link from a internal page in my app and then open this page.

I tried with this.navCtrl.push, but I don´t know why it didnt worked.
Here's my code:

```
       click(){
         this.barcodeScanner.scan().then((barcodeData) => {
           this.navCtrl.push(barcodeData.text, data);
         }, (err) => {
              alert('Error');
         });
       }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using ionic3 lazyloader or using the deeplinking can achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

**Install this plugin at first.,**

$ ionic plugin add phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner

$ npm install --save @ionic-native/barcode-scanner

**you can import it from**

"import { BarcodeScanner } from '@ionic-native/barcode-scanner';"

**Then create a click button something like "scan" in .html  and code this in .ts file**

```
click() {
BarcodeScanner.scan()
.then((result) => {
if (!result.cancelled) {
      const barcodeData = new BarcodeData(result.text, result.format);
      this.scanDetails(barcodeData);
    }
  })
  .catch((err) => {
   alert(err);
  })
 }

Now just feed the link which you need to open in QRcode and scan it..
```

Comment: This will work like the "window.open" in javascript? I tried using the plugin without ionic, using just javascript and it worked, but typescript is different, so I don't know how to do it.

Comment: typescript is nothing but superset of JS.,the code which i mentioned will work just fine with the .ts file